# Add html string to DOM as element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there anyway to create a string and add to the DOM? And having Javascript to understand the elements in the string?

```
I tried the below and 4th line gives error:
var bmdiv = document.createElement('div');
bmdiv.setAttribute('id', 'myDiv');
var str = "<b>aa</b>";
bmdiv.innerHTML(str);
```

I need to add several tags in str to the DIV myDiv

I need NOT to use jQuery since the script will not load jQuery
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `innerHTML` property is not a function, you should *assign* it like this:

```
var bmdiv = document.createElement('div');
bmdiv.setAttribute('id', 'myDiv');
var str = "<b>aa</b>";
bmdiv.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: See what jQuery does to developers, they now expect every API to be a function :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bmdiv.innerHTML = str;
```

Another way to do this is to manually create the DOM structure for each of the tags, then append them into the div.

Comment: That doesn't append, `bmdiv.innerHTML += str;` is