# How do I append data from localStorage to an element on the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Currently working on a Bookmark manager that saves data to localstorage, then append the stored data from the localstorage to the DOM but the `fetchUrl()` doesn't append the code to the DOM.

Please find below what I have tried:

```js
document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',storeFormInput)

var bookmarks= []

function storeFormInput(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    //get input values
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var urlInput = document.getElementById('url').value;

 
//create a bookmark object
let bookmark = {
    name: nameInput,
    url: urlInput
}
// store bookmark in bookmarks array
bookmarks.push(bookmark);
 localStorage.setItem('bookmarksKey',JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
 fetchUrl()
}

function fetchUrl(){
    var displayResult = document.getElementById('result');

    var localDb = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarksKey'))
    displayResult += localDb

}
```

```css
body{
    background: #EFEFEF
}
.content{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

input{
    border-radius: 3px;
}


input[type="text"]{
    color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    margin:  auto;
}

#subButton{
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:  auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}

.blue{
    background-color: #3D78FF;
    color: #fff;
}

input[type="button"]:hover{

}

#saved{
    background:#20c65b !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:1px 5px;
    color: #fff;
}


#resultPanel{
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 250px;
}

#visit{

}
```

```html
 <div class="content">
     <h1>Website Bookmarker</h1>
     <form id="form1">
         <label for="">Name: </label> 
         <input type="text" name="" id="name" placeholder="Website">
         <br>
         <label for="">Url: </label><input type="text" name="" id="url" placeholder="Website">
        <button class="blue" id="subButton" type="button">Submit</button>
            
     </form>
 </div>

 <div id="displayResult">
     <div id="saved">
         <h3>SAVED BOOKMARK</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S I tried calling `fetchUrl()` on body load like

```
<body onload="fetchUrl()">
```

**However, whenever I click the submit button, it doesn't append the `localDb` to the DOM until I refresh the page then it duplicates all the data stored in local storage in the DOM.**

Comment: `displayResult` refers to an HTML element, so `displayResult += …` makes no sense - you can not “add” or concatenate a string value to an element reference. Maybe you wanted `displayResult.innerHTML += …` or something similar?

Comment: This is two questions. How to use localstorage and how to add to the DOM. From your code, it seems that you're confused on how to manipulate the DOM as you're trying to concatenate to an element reference. This has been answered countless times in many ways on SO and would advise you to search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add html string to DOM as element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227007/add-html-string-to-dom-as-element)

Comment: @Emobe I can now add the data from localDb into the DOM which doesn't show until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
var displayResult = document.getElementById('result');
```

you get a reference to the dom element. So you can work with the [dom element API](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)  . Display it in a simple way:

```
displayResult.innerHTML = '<pre>' + localStorage.getItem('bookmarksKey') + '</pre>'
```

But if you want to display it in a beatiful way, you have to go through your data and build element with the api.
So first study the api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet

```
window.onload = function() {
    fetchUrl();
};
document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',storeFormInput)
var bookmarks= []
function storeFormInput(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    //get input values
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var urlInput = document.getElementById('url').value;


    //create a bookmark object
    let bookmark = {
        name: nameInput,
        url: urlInput
    }
    // store bookmark in bookmarks array
    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarksKey',JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    fetchUrl()
}

    function prepareHTML(data){
    var str = ''
    if(data.length){
        str += '<table>'
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        str += '<tr>'
            str += '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>' 
            str += '<td>' + data[i].url + '</td>'
        str += '</tr>' 
        }
        str += '</table>'
    }
    return str
}
```

Prepare HTML from Array of elements and set in innerHTML of results div...